# Calculate the corresponding point from one 2D plane in another

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have a Plane A (defined by 2D points A1,A2,A3,A4) and a Plane B (defined by 2D points B1,B2,B3,B4).
This is the calibration process.

The problem I am trying to solve is how do I calculate a Point X, from Plane A, in Plane B?

I read about homography, and transformation matrices, but I did not find anything in relation to one point calculation.

I am using C# and EMGU to do the code part, but any sample would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have some input points that you choose, and you want to warp that image to be placed at your desired points. If so, you can use the code below as a templete.

```
//Get the input image
Mat img = CvInvoke.Imread("img.png", ImreadModes.AnyColor);

//Declare an image that will hold the output
Mat output = new Mat(img.Width, img.Height);

//Get two points on the input image
Point point = new Point(0, 0);
Point point2 = new Point(100, 0);
Point point3 = new Point(0, 100);
Point point4 = new Point(100, 100);

//Store the points in a list
PointF[] srcPoints = new PointF[] { point, point2, point3, point4 };

//Declare where you want the image to end up
Point point5 = new Point(50, 0);
Point point6 = new Point(150, 0);
Point point7 = new Point(50, 100);
Point point8 = new Point(150, 100);

//Store those points in the list
PointF[] dstPoints = new PointF[] { point5, point6, point7, point8 };

//Calculate the homography matrix
Mat matrix = CvInvoke.FindHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints, RobustEstimationAlgorithm.AllPoints);

//Warp the image
CvInvoke.WarpPerspective(img, output, matrix, new Size(output.Width, output.Height), Inter.Area, Warp.Default);
```

Here you just read in the image you want to use, declare the starting and ending points, then just pass those variables into the two functions to do all the calculations for you. Of course you will have to change some values to fit your specific circumstances, but this is how I have done this type of problem in the past.

I hope this is what you were looking for, and let me know if you have any questions.